# Can I modify maxclients in redis cloud?

Tags: caching, redis, node-redis, redis-cli, redisclient

Currently, I am using the Redis cloud service and using the free plan. As a student, I had to use the free plan, but Redis cloud has a limit on the number of keys.

I have 27MB left, but I can't use it anymore because of the Redis client error [ErrorReply: ERR max number of clients reached].

The reason for the large capacity is not caching for fast response, but to honor the API request limit.

Please tell me how to fix maxclients in Redis cloud.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGrba.png)

I thought of storing the response as a single large object by combining it into one big data chunk, but if maxclients is configurable, my efforts will be wasted, so I'm asking with hope.

Comment: the free plan should allow you up to 30 connections.  how many clients did you have connected at the time of this error?